# Highcharts: wrap column chart month ranges in year

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm building a stacked column chart using highcharts which shows data by month over a 24 month period which will often go over three years.

My current code is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Mar', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Dec', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'May', 'Apr', 'Mar', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Dec', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'May', 'Apr']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total investments'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Bad',
            data: [90000, 100000, 110000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'OK',
            data: [0, 100000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100000, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Good',
            data: [250000, 290000, 210000, 300000, 320000, 190000, 200000, 210000, 210000, 210000, 250000, 290000, 210000, 300000, 320000, 190000, 200000, 210000, 210000, 210000]
        }]
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle of my current set up is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mister_cairns/jTqaF/) and hoping someone can how I'd be able to wrap each group of months in their relevant year as shown in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extension, which allows to group categories.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories